# Area calculation and RegionPlot

Tags: regions, plotting

I want to color the region and calculate the area between $$y^{2}=3x$$ and $$y=2x-6$$. I tried

```
Solve[y^2 == 3 x && y == 2 x - 6, {x, y}]
RegionPlot[{y^2 < 3*x && y > 2*x - 6}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -3, 10}]
```

The area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val = Values@Solve[y^2 == 3 x && y == 2 x - 6, {x, y}];
p1 = Plot[{Sqrt[3 x], -Sqrt[3 x], 2 x - 6}, {x, 0, 6}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Black];
p2 = Plot[{Sqrt[3 x], -Sqrt[3 x]}, {x, 0, val[[1, 1]]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> LightBlue,
    PlotStyle -> Black];
p3 = Plot[{Sqrt[3 x], 2 x - 6}, {x, val[[1, 1]], val[[2, 1]]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> LightBlue,
    PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[p1, p2, p3]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[((y + 6)/2 - y^2/3), {y, val[[1, 2]], val[[2, 2]]}]
```

$\displaystyle\int_{\frac{3}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{17}\right)}^{\frac{3}{4} \left(1+\sqrt{17}\right)} \left(\frac{y+6}{2}-\frac{y^2}{3}\right) \, dy$

> $\frac{51 \sqrt{17}}{16}$

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
Area@ImplicitRegion[{y^2 < 3*x && y > 2*x - 6}, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, -3, 10}}]
```

> -(3/16) (3 Sqrt[17] - Sqrt[2] (9 - Sqrt[17])^(3/2) - 
>      Sqrt[2] (9 + Sqrt[17])^(3/2))

and

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[{y^2 < 3*x && y > 2*x - 6}, {{x, 0, 5}, {y, -3, 10}}],
 MaxCellMeasure -> (1 -> 0.1)
 ]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can set the `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion` options of `RegionPlot` to higher values.

Comment: Thanks. Can I have a better Plot?